# How to create custom html templates in CKEditor?

Tags: html, templates, ckeditor

I am looking to create custom templates in CKEditor and then use the source code of the template elsewhere. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score -2):

You can customize your CKEditor here

> http://ckeditor.com/builder

You can choose your Preset, Plugin and Skins, or language.

Or you called that "Template".

You can use this link reference to advance customization too.

> http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/